# Read CSV file with unused header rows, footer rows and column parsing issue

Tags: r, csv, tidyverse

I want to import a bank statement in CSV format that contains multiple rows of headers and footers that are not required.

I use this `skip = 7` to skip first 6 rows and `col_types` to select columns required for automation.

```
read_csv(files[1], skip = 7, col_types = cols_only(AMOUNT = col_character(), `BILL REF NO.` = col_character()))
```

Here is the result. I want the `AMOUNT` to be `double`, so I change the col_types.

```
A tibble: 34,825 x 2
   AMOUNT       `BILL REF NO.`      
   <chr>        <chr>               
 1 "=\"17.58\"" 10000572874151776433
 2 "=\"20.88\"" 10001648407332077912
 3 "=\"70.60\"" 10002560021836683570
 4 "=\"31.60\"" 10002744168017800627
 5 "=\"80.00\"" 10003770035224984569
 6 "=\"71.70\"" 10005255656409587173
 7 "=\"27.97\"" 10005611886756396773
 8 "=\"30.00\"" 10005808228105071391
 9 "=\"34.58\"" 10006408254089150090
10 "=\"27.81\"" 10006412992762689126
# ... with 34,815 more rows
```

Code below change the column types but the result shows `AMOUNT` to be `NA`. What can I do to make it right?

```
read_csv(files[1], skip = 7, col_types = cols_only(AMOUNT = col_double(), `BILL REF NO.` = col_character()))
```

```
# A tibble: 34,825 x 2
   AMOUNT `BILL REF NO.`      
    <dbl> <chr>               
 1     NA 10000572874151776433
 2     NA 10001648407332077912
 3     NA 10002560021836683570
 4     NA 10002744168017800627
 5     NA 10003770035224984569
 6     NA 10005255656409587173
 7     NA 10005611886756396773
 8     NA 10005808228105071391
 9     NA 10006408254089150090
10     NA 10006412992762689126
# ... with 34,815 more rows
```

Comment: The equal sign at the start of each value is forcing the column to be a character object.  Most likely you need to read the column as a character, strip the = and the quotes and then convert to a double.

Comment: ok, tq for reply. i will try that later. Forgot to ask in my question, is there a proper way to exclude certain rows at the bottom of dataset?? I know `skip` will ignore top rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @Dave2e, you need to correct the data after importing it. One way is to use `parse_number` function since you are already using `readr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

read_csv(files[1], skip = 7) %>%
  mutate(AMOUNT = parse_number(AMOUNT))
```

Comment: i will try that later. Forgot to ask in my question, is there a proper way to exclude certain rows at the bottom of dataset?? I know `skip` will ignore top rows.

Comment: I don't know any such parameter in `read_csv` but you can use `slice`/`slice_tail` to drop the last rows.